# Java does not trusting any SSL Certificate on Windows

Tags: java, ssl, gradle

When building with Maven or Gradle, the dependency download process is failing because Java does not trust any of their SSL certs on Windows. Is there anyway to make Java trust the certificates from the Maven repositories?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1) You can add all the CA and intermediate certicate of the maven repository to your Java trust store using keytool command. 
You can do this by

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <SERVER>:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >certificate.pem
```

This will save the certicate in local file called cert.pem
Now you have add this certiicate to your trust store
conver to .der format

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der
```

add to trust store.

```
keytool -import -alias your-alias -keystore cacerts -file certificate.der
```

2) If you want to by pass the trust you could use the following property while runing mvn. 
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true

3) If you are planning to by pass the Java Trsut store and want to your own trust store you could set the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trust.jks \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=  \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/directory/mycertificate.p12 \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=XXXXXX"
```

reference : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html

Comment: Can you provide me with the specific steps to perform option 1? I've tried with several recipes from the internet, but none work.

Comment: I have updated the answer with how to add the certificate to trust store an URL

Answer (score 1):

The simple and possible way to solve the problem and make it work for now and the future is to add the public certificate of Maven to Java trusted store(ie java key store).

**Creating your own java key store and mapping it to the default will be a difficult task.**

> Just get the certificate(public certificate of Maven),  then follow
>   the below steps

You can use openssl client or any browser if the server supports https to get the public digital certificate. You can click view certificate in browser and save it by clicking the left most icon on the Address bar (with https striked{must be striked or red as the certificate is untrusted} symbol)

To get the certificate via openSSL command (I assume you will not have openssl by default in windows, so its better to follow the browser method, else download an SSL client to get the certificate, I can give you the tool name if you couldn't find any tool).

> **Follow the below steps once you got the certificate.**
>
> **1)Go to your [Java installation path]\jre\lib\security**
>
> **2)(Windows) Open admin command line there using 'cmd' and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**
>
> **(make sure you are in the [Java installation path]\jre\lib\security on command prompt, else you must have set the path to system
>   environmental variable)**
>
> **3)Run keytool to import certificate:**
>
> **....\bin\keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias yourAliasName -file
>   path\to\certificate.cer**
>
> *You will get prompted for the password for the keystore*
>
> The default password for java keystore is **changeit**

done. All the leaf certificate from Maven will get trusted by java from now.

*To verify whether your configuration is correct you can use*

**keytool -list -keystore cacerts**

Enter keystore password:  changeit

This lists the certificates present in the trusted store(java keystore)

Comment: Above are the steps I followed to import a certificate for testing purposes for my project, As I have signed my java applet with a selfsigned (un trusted certificate by default). It works